# How to add a note in imageview like marked map

Tags: android, imageview

I have a application.
It have a imageview activity.
How to add a note in it like marker in map?
What library support this? if you know please tell me know.
Thank very much.

Comment: Note of what? Can you show some image or link of what you want to code?

Comment: Like Marked in map, i want to mark a point in my image? how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Use BitMap and Canvas:

```
drawable.draw(canvas);
Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.search_marker_icon);
canvas.drawBitmap(marker, 10, 10, null);
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawCircle(30, 30, 5, mPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    if (drawLock.availablePermits() <= 0) {
        drawLock.release();
    }
}
 super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```